# Создание кнопки в HTML

Tags: html, css

Создал текстовой документ, в нем написал

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; windows-1251">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<a class="botton">Клик</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Сохранил его в расширении html. Далее создал ещё текстовой документ, в нем написал

```
.botton {
    backround-image: url("http://info-dvd.ru/bbm/images/komis_table/forex-preview.png");
    backround-repeat: no pereat;
    border: 0px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Сохранил его в расширении css. Изображение не появляется, что я сделал не так? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: как назвал файл .css?

Comment: да и кнопку ты не создаешь, просто рисунок в div пытаешся вставить

Comment: Тег <link> пиши без закрывающего тега

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка:

```
backround-image: url("http://info-dvd.ru/bbm/images/komis_table/forex-preview.png");
backround-repeat: no pereat;
```

Правильно:

```
background-image: url("http://info-dvd.ru/bbm/images/komis_table/forex-preview.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Но весь background-image попросту не влезет в размер ссылки. Правильнее надо так:

```
<a class="botton"><img src="http://info-dvd.ru/bbm/images/komis_table/forex-preview.png" alt="Ссылка"><br>Клик</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ссылка - это не *контейнер*.
2. Пользуйтесь [блоком (див)](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/gwuBV/)

Comment: `display: block;` запретили что ли?)